# Loading em AngularFireAuthGuard

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire

Alguma maneira de implementar um loading no CanActivate em Angular 11?

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuthGuard, redirectUnauthorizedTo } from '@angular/fire/auth-guard';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { ListaComponent } from './lista/lista.component';
import { MensagemComponent } from './mensagem/mensagem.component';

const redirectUnauthorizedToLogin = () => redirectUnauthorizedTo(['/login']);

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'lista',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'lista',
        component: ListaComponent,
        canActivate: [ AngularFireAuthGuard ], 
        data: { authGuardPipe: redirectUnauthorizedToLogin }
    },
    {
        path: 'mensagem',
        component: MensagemComponent
    }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class ViewsRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

não existe uma maneira padrão de fazer isto pelo angular routing.
uma coisa que pode fazer é um componente de loading que carrega e checa as coisas. e redireciona para a tela alvo utilizando router.navigate (esta segunda utilizando o canActivate)
outra coisa pode tentar usar Router Resolver que carrega dados antes do componente for carregado mas mesmo assim não há como mostrar nada enquanto isto pelo que sei.
Encontrei isto no stackoverflow
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43004412/is-there-a-way-to-display-a-loading-screen-while-waiting-for-an-angular-2-route/43004542

Comment: Interessante... vou dar uma olhada mas penso que vai de encontro com o que preciso. Obrigado